# How to validate no-mapped property

Tags: validation, symfony, sonata-admin

I defined no-mapped property in configureFormFields function

```
add('numberOfSubproducts', 'integer',array('mapped' => false,'required' => true, 'data'=> 1))
```

and constraint in validate function

```
assertRange(['min' => 0, 'max' => 9999])
```

and I get error :

Neither property `numberOfSubproducts` nor method `getNumberOfSubproducts()` nor method `isNumberOfSubproducts()` exists in class `path\to\entity`

How to define constraint for no-mapped property in SonataAdminBundle in right way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate field directly in form, thanks to `constraints` property. See [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-option-constraints).

```
$builder
   ->add('lastName', 'text', array(
       'constraints' => array(
           new NotBlank(),
           new Length(array('min' => 3)),
       ),
   ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to define it as a property of your entity without stating it as an ORM\Column.

Using annotations, you do it like that :

***in your entity class declaration*** :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

// ...

/**
 * Assert\Range(min=0, max=9999)
 */
protected $numberOfSubproducts;

// ...

public function getNumberOfSubproducts()
{
    return $this->numberOfSubproducts;
}

public function setNumberOfSubproducts($numberOfSubproducts)
{
    $this->numberOfSubproducts = $numberOfSubproducts;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: forgottenbas' answer is the cleanest solution, mine is just a kind a nice hack ;)

Comment: Sometimes is very usefull to store properties in entity, but form can be not mapped to entity or model =)

Answer (score 0):

First way to validate form is by FormType
http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/forms.html#form-validation

And also you can use validation groups if you want custom validating (only those that applied to group) 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/forms.html#validation-groups

Second is create form as simple call createFormBuilder(). And input there you custom validation to each field
http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/forms.html#building-the-form